# Rigid bodies passing through

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

[Blender 2.73a]
I have a scene, where a helmet is falling on a surface.

[image]

It is quite complex: high-poly helmet, every link in chainmail is a separate element and all this stuff are rigid bodies. I want them to act physically correct, that is why so. All modifiers and transformations are applied: objects are clean meshes. I've already done simulation tests with this model earlier (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gszj0GUkigI), now I've updated the model and try to make a new simulation, but it fails:

[image]

Surface (was a passive body plane first, now an active non-dynamic cube — doesn't matter) first collides, but then chains and helmet pass through it.
I've tried everything — no idea how to fix this.

Here are screenshots of settings:

Helmet:

[image]

Chainmail:

[image]

Surface:

[image]

Scene:

[image]

(all objects are real-size, high values of steps and iterations always well helped increase accuracy)

Any ideas, why is this?

**UPD**

Subdivided surface, increased steps to 1600 and solver iterations to 120. No luck

[image]

Comment: you can try to add more geometry to your ground. (subdivide it)

Comment: this matters? O_o ok, I'll try

Comment: can help sometimes

Comment: Have you applied the scale to all of the meshes?

Comment: Yes. Everything is applied

Comment: Have you tried playing with the solver iterations? Also, is the scene physically scaled? that can make a difference?

Comment: I'd try making the surface a cube, not a plane, it may help.

Comment: It is a cube already. And all is real-size. That is written in the post. I've increased solver iterations to 100, waiting now

Comment: Subdivided surface, increased steps to 1600 and solver iterations to 120. No luck. See gif in post UPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with some tries I've come to understanding, that problem is not in the surface, but in chains. In Blender's physics engine mass is corresponding to durability (sic!). So, realsize chains with a calculated mass near 1g each is too weak and they "break" during collisions. The only working workaround was to scale everything up several times and increase the mass of everything...

Comment: Yep, rigid body sims usually need to be scaled up quite a bit for the calculations to not wack up on small objects.  Sometimes this will make the objects move slower (I am not talking about lag), if this happens just increase the overall sim speed, check out [Andrew Price's rigid body tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/).